# bUSB slot not working at all on any Debian-based derivative

Tags: drivers, usb, hardware-compatibility

I tried to install first ParrotOS, a debian-based distro, several times. It always got stuck at the "Detect CD-ROM" phase during any installation interface. It made no difference, if I used the GTK Installer or not, etc. All had exactly the same problems. I flashed several different USB thumb drives for this and in the end I even burnt it onto a DVD, just to be sure and since usually that solved everything. (ParrotOS is an ISO9960 image, so it has some special needs, but I know how to deal with that from experience.) This derivative uses the plain standard Debian installer, nothing else.
Just to check, I wanted to boot into the Live system and install from there, even though that's usually more prone to errors. Then every time I started up (of course even with extreme failsafe settings) after about 1 minute of starting up it showed me `(initramfs) Unable to find a medium containing a live file system`. So this has frustrated me for days now, because there was no viable solution to this on the internet at all.
After that I tried several other Debian based distros. They all have **exactly the same** issues, regarding both the live boot and installation. I realized that the error lies within Debian itself.

So basically that's where I was left at: my USB drives somehow don't get recognized at all and therefore I couldn't install anything Debian-like. (No, my laptop has no DVD drive.) Even the external BD drive I have, got recognized as a USB device by the UEFI (image was set up accordingly to that, as well) and the distros.

After all this frustration, I decided to do something drastic and made the internal cache SSD of the laptop free for a different use. Which was a huge issue on its own, due to different reasons, but that's not important here.
I flashed ParrotOS onto the SSD and then booted into the menu. I tried to install it through the generic installer again, but that exited with the same error as mentioned above. Then I wanted to boot into the Live system and voilá, this time it actually worked. I got into the live system and started the installer, but it crashed constantly.
So I flashed the internal SSD again, but this time with the newest *siduction*. I could boot into the live system and get the installer to work finally. I was happy, that finally it worked out.

Sadly after that, something become apparent to me. I thought there were just some updates needed, but that was not the reason. At first my mouse didn't work. Then I realized, that all USB peripherals wouldn't work at all. I searched a lot for a fix regarding this, but in the end I realized that they were all misleading. (For example mouse buffer overflow, etc.)

The conclusion of all these problems:
Debian doesn't recognize the USB ports. At all. Not even a little.

Now is it a driver problem? I doubt that, since there is nothing special about these USB 3.0 ports and Linux should handle that easily. Also I read that even if the driver doesn't work or is faulty or missing, then the ports should still make a reaction in the logs.
I'm not a low-level expert like this and that's why I need your proficient help.
I hope the whole story wasn't too lengthy, but I wanted to make sure to provide as much information as possible without missing out on mentioning some little but (maybe critical?) detail.

dmesg **FULL** output:

https://pastebin.com/k2Z8dwvi

dmesg | tail -40 output:

```
[   11.932394] snd_hda_codec_realtek hdaudioC0D0:    mono: mono_out=0x0
[   11.932395] snd_hda_codec_realtek hdaudioC0D0:    inputs:
[   11.932397] snd_hda_codec_realtek hdaudioC0D0:      Mic=0x18
[   11.932398] snd_hda_codec_realtek hdaudioC0D0:      Internal Mic=0x12
[   11.949276] ieee80211 phy0: Selected rate control algorithm 'iwl-agn-rs'
[   12.105509] snd_hda_intel 0000:00:1b.0: bound 0000:00:02.0 (ops i915_audio_component_bind_ops [i915])
[   12.107749] input: HDA Intel PCH Mic as /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1b.0/sound/card0/input11
[   12.107812] input: HDA Intel PCH Headphone as /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1b.0/sound/card0/input12
[   12.107877] input: HDA Intel PCH HDMI/DP,pcm=3 as /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1b.0/sound/card0/input13
[   12.107937] input: HDA Intel PCH HDMI/DP,pcm=7 as /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1b.0/sound/card0/input14
[   12.224425] media: Linux media interface: v0.10
[   12.277084] Linux video capture interface: v2.00
[   12.525901] intel_rapl: Found RAPL domain package
[   12.525903] intel_rapl: Found RAPL domain core
[   12.525904] intel_rapl: Found RAPL domain uncore
[   12.525909] intel_rapl: RAPL package 0 domain package locked by BIOS
[   12.615904] iwlwifi 0000:03:00.0 wlp3s0: renamed from wlan0
[   12.655144] uvcvideo: Found UVC 1.00 device Integrated Camera (04f2:b315)
[   12.663498] uvcvideo 4-1.6:1.0: Entity type for entity Extension 4 was not initialized!
[   12.663500] uvcvideo 4-1.6:1.0: Entity type for entity Extension 3 was not initialized!
[   12.663501] uvcvideo 4-1.6:1.0: Entity type for entity Processing 2 was not initialized!
[   12.663503] uvcvideo 4-1.6:1.0: Entity type for entity Camera 1 was not initialized!
[   12.663566] input: Integrated Camera as /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1d.0/usb4/4-1/4-1.6/4-1.6:1.0/input/input15
[   12.663613] usbcore: registered new interface driver uvcvideo
[   12.663613] USB Video Class driver (1.1.1)
[   12.797956] usb 3-1.3: USB disconnect, device number 4
[   15.297792] EXT4-fs (sda8): mounted filesystem with ordered data mode. Opts: (null)
[   18.059519] Bluetooth: BNEP (Ethernet Emulation) ver 1.3
[   18.059521] Bluetooth: BNEP filters: protocol multicast
[   18.059525] Bluetooth: BNEP socket layer initialized
[   20.476556] nf_conntrack version 0.5.0 (16384 buckets, 65536 max)
[   21.349213] r8169 0000:04:00.0: firmware: direct-loading firmware rtl_nic/rtl8168e-3.fw
[   21.464298] r8169 0000:04:00.0 enp4s0: link down
[   21.464300] r8169 0000:04:00.0 enp4s0: link down
[   21.464387] IPv6: ADDRCONF(NETDEV_UP): enp4s0: link is not ready
[   23.530954] r8169 0000:04:00.0 enp4s0: link up
[   23.530984] IPv6: ADDRCONF(NETDEV_CHANGE): enp4s0: link becomes ready
[   23.617895] 8021q: 802.1Q VLAN Support v1.8
[   23.674073] NET: Registered protocol family 17
[   48.816497] fuse init (API version 7.26)


Bus 004 Device 004: ID 04f2:b315 Chicony Electronics Co., Ltd 
Bus 004 Device 003: ID 0483:91d1 STMicroelectronics Sensor Hub
Bus 004 Device 002: ID 8087:0024 Intel Corp. Integrated Rate Matching Hub
Bus 004 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 003 Device 003: ID 03eb:8206 Atmel Corp. 
Bus 003 Device 002: ID 8087:0024 Intel Corp. Integrated Rate Matching Hub
Bus 003 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0003 Linux Foundation 3.0 root hub
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub


Bus 004 Device 004: ID 04f2:b315 Chicony Electronics Co., Ltd 
Bus 004 Device 003: ID 0483:91d1 STMicroelectronics Sensor Hub
Bus 004 Device 002: ID 8087:0024 Intel Corp. Integrated Rate Matching Hub
Bus 004 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 003 Device 003: ID 03eb:8206 Atmel Corp. 
Bus 003 Device 002: ID 8087:0024 Intel Corp. Integrated Rate Matching Hub
Bus 003 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0003 Linux Foundation 3.0 root hub
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
```

If I re-plug different USB devices several times, nothing changes in `dmesg`.

If I should add any more logs, tell me.

```
00:00.0 Host bridge: Intel Corporation 3rd Gen Core processor DRAM Controller (rev 09)                                                                                  
00:02.0 VGA compatible controller: Intel Corporation 3rd Gen Core processor Graphics Controller (rev 09)                                                                
00:14.0 USB controller: Intel Corporation 7 Series/C210 Series Chipset Family USB xHCI Host Controller (rev 04)                                                         
00:16.0 Communication controller: Intel Corporation 7 Series/C216 Chipset Family MEI Controller #1 (rev 04)                                                             
00:1a.0 USB controller: Intel Corporation 7 Series/C216 Chipset Family USB Enhanced Host Controller #2 (rev 04)                                                         
00:1b.0 Audio device: Intel Corporation 7 Series/C216 Chipset Family High Definition Audio Controller (rev 04)                                                          
00:1c.0 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation 7 Series/C216 Chipset Family PCI Express Root Port 1 (rev c4)                                                                     
00:1c.1 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation 7 Series/C210 Series Chipset Family PCI Express Root Port 2 (rev c4)                                                              
00:1c.3 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation 7 Series/C216 Chipset Family PCI Express Root Port 4 (rev c4)                                                                     
00:1d.0 USB controller: Intel Corporation 7 Series/C216 Chipset Family USB Enhanced Host Controller #1 (rev 04)                                                         
00:1f.0 ISA bridge: Intel Corporation HM77 Express Chipset LPC Controller (rev 04)                                                                                      
00:1f.2 SATA controller: Intel Corporation 7 Series Chipset Family 6-port SATA Controller [AHCI mode] (rev 04)                                                          
00:1f.3 SMBus: Intel Corporation 7 Series/C216 Chipset Family SMBus Controller (rev 04)                                                                                 
02:00.0 Unassigned class [ff00]: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. RTS5229 PCI Express Card Reader (rev 01)
03:00.0 Network controller: Intel Corporation Centrino Wireless-N 2230 (rev c4)
04:00.0 Ethernet controller: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. RTL8111/8168/8411 PCI Express Gigabit Ethernet Controller (rev 07)


Linux hostname 4.12.9-towo.1-siduction-amd64 #1 SMP PREEMPT siduction 4.12-16 (2017-08-25) x86_64 GNU/Linux
```

Comment: Your USB hubs do appear in your PCI listing, and your dmesg does contain a USB disconnect (and mentions USB video, so a webcam is detected). Can you `lsusb`?

Comment: It might has something to do with XHCI. Apparently the devices detected are internal (builtin touchpad and webcam). However, that's not the only thing that differentiate them. They are also ultimately connected to either of the two 2.0 root hub (bus 3 and 4) that are managed by an EHCI controller (hence the EHCI driver), while the the other 2.0 root hub (bus 1) and the only 3.0 root hub (bus 2) that has no device found to be connected to them are managed by an XHCI controller (hence the XHCI driver). The external ports on the laptop are probably provided by the two hubs.

Comment: TL;DR, try switch from XHCI mode to EHCI mode if the BIOS/UEFI setting provides such option and see if it changes anything.

Comment: @Fox The text didn't format correctly, please scroll down the dmesg tail to see lsusb.

Comment: @TomYan I thought about switching UEFI settings, too, but sadly there is only an AHCI mode which I can switch to *Compatibility" mode which means that my HDD won't be recognized as far as I remember.

Comment: AHCI is irrelevant here. It's the mode of the SATA controllers but not USB. In that case you might want to see if the ports work with other distro (that has a kernel of different version, for example Arch). As you said, the kernel doesn't spit anything when you insert a USB device, there's not much we can help.

Comment: @TomYan I was planning on checking that out, too. I guess I'll do that tomorrow or another day soon and post the results here.

Comment: Btw, has this computer ever got Windows 8+ installed? If so was the ports tested back then?

Comment: @TomYan This laptop was bought with Windows 8 pre-installed but was upgraded to W10. I can't comment on how it was back then, because I got it from my friend when it was already upgraded to Windows 10. But I'm pretty sure that it worked.

Comment: Can you try bootoption `acpi=noirq` ? These parameters disable the PCI IRQ routing.

Comment: `dmesg` is not enough, could you please show an `lsusb` and `lspci` output? What is your kernel version (`uname -a`)? Which debian is it, stretch?

Comment: Check out the additional output.